# Distinguishing Isentropic Process; Are all things in an insulated cylinder considered reversible adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

How much work is necessary to compress air in an insulated cylinder from 0.20m^3 to 0.01m^3. Use T1 = 20C and P1 = 100 kPa.

I don't need to solution or the answer. I already have it.

But I think the problem gives no clues on when its an reversible adiabatic or not. difference being if it is, the work involves the specific heat ratio k.

W = (P2V2 - P1V1)/1-k

if not its simply

W = P(V2-V1)

It is implied that the volume changes.. but the temperature,pressure does not? are all things in an insulated cylinder... reversible adiabatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying that it is insulated they are saying that heat can't enter or leave the system. So you have no change in entropy due to $\Delta S = \Delta Q/T$. So if the entropy is constant throughout the process you can use the reversible adiabatic formula. And yes the temperature and pressure do change as you compress the gas (they increase).

Strictly speaking the 'reversible' part is in question. If there are internal processes such as friction or viscosity, the entropy of the gas may increase. But in that case the work needed would be even higher since all else being equal higher entropy means higher internal energy. But they only ask how much work is "necessary". And even if they didn't say that you could assume that from the context as a homework problem.